# How Do I Improve Javascript Table Update Performance Issues?

Tags: javascript, performance

So I'm running an app and I'm allowing the user to enter data into a table.  Easy enough...I'm also trying to auto add the sums of the totals as they enter the totals.  This works well enough when I do something like...

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name$='-budget_line_item_february']", function(){
  update_budget_total_february();
});

function update_budget_total_february()
{
  var total = 0;
  $("input[name$='-budget_line_item_february']:visible").each(function(index, element) {
      var val = parseFloat($(element).val());
      if( !isNaN( val )){
           total += val;
        }
      });
      $("#id_february_disabled_budget_total").val((total).toFixed(2));
      $("#id_february_budget_total").val((total).toFixed(2));
}
```

For a limited number of rows.  As the rows grow....I'm noticing that performance is starting to take a hit.  I'd rather not have to remove this functionality...and have them have to click a button to total everything....but it seems as if I allow unlimited rows...performance will suffer at some point?  Because they can enter as many rows as they'd like I realize this is somewhat of a performance impacting operation...correct?  Is there any way to provide this functionality in a manner whereas performance won't take as much of a hit?

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: You might want to throttle/debounce the logic so that `update_budget_total_febrary()` is only called after the user stops inputting.

Comment: @Terry  Thanks for the thought.  So you're suggesting a separate button?

Comment: Nope. See https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Comment: After how many rows do you notice performance issues? Have you profiled your code? (browsers let you record performance profiles)

Comment: @Terry Thanks.  Will explore.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the input.  I have recorded it and explored a bit.  It's about after 100 rows that I'm starting to see some degradation in performance.

Comment: Mmh, that doesn't sound like a lot. I wonder if the `[name$='-budget_line_item_february']:visible` selector is somehow expensive. Maybe try without the `:visible` selector?

Comment: @FelixKling I need the visible selector...but will play with and experiment.  Thanks for the thought.